# Differences between Program.cs and App.razor

Tags: razor, blazor

What's the differences bettwen `Program.cs` and `App.razor` in Blazor (Server Side)? I tested and i know that the `App.razor` is executed after `Program.cs`, when i need execute a method before App start i put the method inside `CreateHostBuilder`.
When should i use `App.razor` and `Program.cs`? What can i do in `Program.cs` and not in `App.razor`?(and viceverse) What's the adventages?

*Program.cs*

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(async webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                await MethodAsync();
            });

    private static async Task MethodAsync()
    {
        //body
    }
```

*App.razor*

```
@code
{
  protected override void OnInitialized()
  {
    await MethodAsync();
  }
  private static async Task MethodAsync()
  {
     //body
  }
}
```

**NOTE:** IM REFERING AT THE C# CODE AND HOW IT WORKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Program.cs

The app's entry point that sets up the:

. ASP.NET Core host (Blazor Server)

. WebAssembly host (Blazor WebAssembly): The code in this file is unique to apps created from the Blazor WebAssembly template (blazorwasm).

. The App component is the root component of the app. The App component is specified as the app DOM element (...) to the root component collection (builder.RootComponents.Add("app")).

. Services are added and configured (for example, builder.Services.AddSingleton<IMyDependency, MyDependency>()).

And

App.razor

The root component of the app that sets up client-side routing using the Router component. The Router component intercepts browser navigation and renders the page that matches the requested address.